# Why virt_to_page(addr) doesn't work?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, operating-system

I want to get page address from this function.

```
virt_to_page(addr);
```

However when I compiled it, this error occur

```
Error implicit declaration of function virt_to_page
```

Even though I already include the mm.h

```
#include<linux/mm.h>
```

Is this function exist somewhere else? And why is it not in mm.h?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-15-sect-1 its declared in

```
<asm/page.h>
```

Comment: It work but how about virt_to_pfn? I tried virt_to_pfn but it doesn't work. Isn't in asm/page.h the same as virt_to_page? @Pras

Comment: @asiandudeCom Same problem here. Did you figure out the right header for virt_to_pfn? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The comment [here](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/infiniband/hw/hfi1/file_ops.c#L444) is a solution:

You just have to call `PFN_DOWN(__pa(virt_addr))` instead.